# Using LIKE SQL statement for simple URL matching

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, redirect

It is possible to use the SQL `LIKE` statement to match a string with or without a trailing slash, as would be found on a typical URL?

Ex.

```
// `table` contains a row where column `path` = "/my-path/"

SELECT * FROM table WHERE path = '/my-path/' // this will return the row above
SELECT * FROM table WHERE path = '/my-path' // this will NOT return the row (no trailing slash)
```

Is there way to use LIKE (or something other than REGEX statement) such that it will grab the row whether or not I pass it `/my-path/` or `/my-path`

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE path LIKE '\/my-path\/?' // (borrowed regex syntax) this would grab a row path = '/my-path/' but would also grab a row with path = '/my-path' (no trailing slash)
```

Basically, I want to set up URL redirects who's records are stored in a database. I pass it the URL path (which may or may not contain a trailing slash) and the respective record is returned, ignoring any possible trailing slashes.

Comment: It looks like you need to use `REGEX`, not `LIKE`.

Comment: yes, Regex will work but the performance is poor. this query scans the entire table and not indexable

Comment: How about `path in ('/my-path', '/my-path/')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN()` to compare with two strings, rather than pattern matching.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE path IN ('/my-path/', '/my-path')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LIKE operator and add the wildcard symbol, %, to the end of your input

```
select * from table1 where path like concat(YOURINPUTHERE,'%')
```